# How do I calculate a truncated-sum approximation?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

[image: Screenshot of the reading].

I'm to take an image, convert it into a set of 3 matrices using `imread()`, then *calculate a truncated-sum approximation to each matrix using `N=1,2,3,4,8,16,32,64,128` terms.* I have the matrices, but I'm not really sure about that last part and the reading is a bit vague. What do they mean by a truncated-sum approximation?

---

Update based on a given answer:

I tried the following:

```
A = double(imread("image.jpg"))/255;

  [U1, S1, V1] = svd(A(:,:,1));
  [U2, S2, V2] = svd(A(:,:,2));
  [U3, S3, V3] = svd(A(:,:,3));

N = 128;    
trunc_image = (U1(1:763,1:N)*S1(1:N,1:N)*V1(1:N,1:691))*255;

imwrite(trunc_image, "truncimg.jpg", "jpg");
```

...but the resulting image looks like this:

[image: screenshot of resulting image]

Comment: Instead of using all the singular values from the [`svd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) of the image, you only the use the largest (I assume in absolute value) ones starting from *the* largest to the (according to your list) 128 largest values.

Comment: @TroyHaskin what do you mean? What do I use these values *for?*

Comment: The image has all that information: the matrix form of the image `A` can be decomposed via an SVD, and the sum `sigma_k * u_k * v_k.'` is exactly `A`.  But, you can approximate `A` by only summing over the largest singular values instead of all of them.  And if `N` (the number of terms in the approximation) is less than `R` (the total number of singular values), you may get a good approximation with a lot less computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform `svd` on an image `I`:

```
[U,S,V] = svd(I,'econ'); %//you get matrices U, S, V
```

`S` will be a `diagonal` matrix, with decreasing singular values along the diagonals.

`Approximation by truncating...` means that I can reconstruct `I'` by zeroing out singular values in `S`:

```
I_recon = U(1:256,1:N)*S(1:N,1:N)*V(1:256,1:N).'; %//Reconstruct by keeping the first N singular values in S.
```

What happens here is that `I_recon` is an image reconstructed from the `N` most significant singular values. The purpose of doing this is so that we can remove `less significant` contributions to the image `I`, and represent `I` with less data.

This is an example of reconstructed images with varying `N`:

[image: SVD reconstruction of I]

Comment: I'm trying what you suggested and it's not working. My resulting image is just a bunch of black, grey, and white lines even at N = 128. This is the code I used: `A = double(imread("image.jpg"))/255;

  [U1, S1, V1] = svd(A(:,:,1));
  [U2, S2, V2] = svd(A(:,:,2));
  [U3, S3, V3] = svd(A(:,:,3)); N = 128;    
trunc_image = (U1(1:763,1:N)*S1(1:N,1:N)*V1(1:N,1:691))*255; imwrite(trunc_image, "truncimg.jpg", "jpg");`

Comment: @whatwhatwhat 1) You dont need to divide by 255 after reading the image (converting to double matrix is enough). 2) Seems like you dont need to use the green and blue channels, so you don't need lines 3 and 4. 3) When reconstructing, be sure to transpose your `V` matrix. 4) Since you are working with `double` type matrix, be sure to divide it by 255 before you display anything.

Comment: The reason I was initially dividing by 255 was because my problem set instructed me to do so. [See this screenshot](http://imgur.com/ezkSX62). However, I don't see any point in doing this!! Do you know why it might be useful to divide by 255 then multiply by 255 before using `imwrite`?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat no idea about that